# How to make Eclipse recognise a Git source tree that was a Bazaar source tree

Tags: eclipse, git, bazaar

I converted my Bazaar repo to a Git repo using fastimport.  Seems to have succeeded as "git log" produces sensible output.

I moved my old bzr checkout directory to another name, then cloned my git repo to the old directory name.

```
$ mv myproj myproj-old-bzr
$ git clone myproj
```

When I start Eclipse I get errors about bazaar.  The .bzr directory has gone (as expected) and I can't find any instance of bzr or baz in the .project or .cproject files, so there must be some info in the workspace directory.

Is there an easy way to I (re)configure Eclipse to use eGit for this project?

Should I start a new project and import the sources or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Got it sorted.

- Right click on the project in Project Explorer, select Team => Disconnect.
- Right click on the project in Project Explorer, select Team => Share Project ...
- Select Git -- my .git directory was present and Ecleipse recongised that an used it accordingly, and all is good in the world :)

eGit is much better than bzr-eclipse.  Bazaar was great and loved it but it doesn't have the support and tools that Git does, so it's time to go with the flow.

Comment: Another solution would have been to delete the project from Eclipse and reimport from the filesystem.